# Can not run Clojure project with Cursive using Leiningen

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, leiningen, cursive

I am unable to run a simple test project using the intellij plugin cursive. I am able to open a REPL without any problems and can even call functions defined in the `core.clj` file.
Running the project directly however yields this error message:

```
Error running 'new-project.core': failed to access class com.intellij.execution.impl.ProcessStreamsSynchronizer from class com.intellij.execution.impl.ConsoleViewRunningState (com.intellij.execution.impl.ProcessStreamsSynchronizer is in unnamed module of loader com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader @402f32ff; com.intellij.execution.impl.ConsoleViewRunningState is in unnamed module of loader com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader @c9a79eb)
```

Intellij run configuration [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlPR3.png). Changing `How to run it` and `What to run` does nothing.

Starting the project via the Leiningen tab yields the same error message.

Comment: Not sure what your `project.clj` looks like, but I usually open a terminal at the bottom of IntelliJ and `lein run`. If you want to run the program from the Cursive REPL, there are other things you may need to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue open about it. 
https://github.com/cursive-ide/cursive/issues/2350

Answer (score 0):

[image: Added project name dependency in project.clj worked for me] 
Also I tried to do `lein run` Let me know if this work for you.